# Is there a way to convert PCM data to some other popular audio format (like mp3, wav etc.)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I've been trying to find a way to convert pcm data from a [VC stream](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/VoiceReceiver?scrollTo=createStream) to something else like mp3/wav but I can't find anything that works, I've tried [this pcm to wav converter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wav-converter) but it didn't work, the wav output file was always over 300 hours long for no reason whatsoever, I've also tried to use opus data instead of pcm because that's an [option](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/typedef/ReceiveStreamOptions) but that doesn't work either. Here is my full code if needed:

```
await message.member.voice.channel.join().then((connection) => {
  const receiver = connection.receiver.createStream(message.member, {
    mode: 'pcm',
    end: 'manual'
  })

  const writer = receiver.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./record-${message.author.id}.pcm`))

  var deniedtimer = setTimeout(async() => {
    await db.set(`shortholdtime-${message.author.id}`, true)
    writer.end()
    message.channel.send('Sorry, I stopped recording because your recording was over 30 minutes long! Because of this, your recording is going to be deleted in 10 minutes instead of 30. To stop you from abusing this system, you will not be able to use the record feature for another 15 minutes.')
    await db.set(`denyrecord-${message.author.id}`, 0)
    var deniedtimertime = setInterval(async() => {
      var deniedtimeleft = await db.get(`denyrecord-${message.author.id}`)
      if (deniedtimeleft >= 900) return async() => {
        clearInterval(deniedtimertime)
        await db.set(`denyrecord-${message.author.id}`, 'false')
      }
      await db.set(`denyrecord-${message.author.id}`, deniedtimeleft + 1)
    })
  }, 30 * 1000 * 60)

  writer.on('finish', async() => {
    if (message.member.voice.channel !== null) {
      message.member.voice.channel.leave()
    } else {
      var vcdata = await db.get(`vcdatarecord-${message.author.id}`)
      var vcdatachannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(vcdata)
      vcdatachannel.leave()
    }
    clearTimeout(deniedtimer)
    var pcmData = fs.readFileSync(`./record-${message.author.id}.pcm`)
    var wavData = wavconvert.encodeWav(pcmData)
    fs.writeFileSync(`./record-${message.author.id}.pcm`, wavData)
    fs.renameSync(`./record-${message.author.id}.pcm`, `./record-${message.author.id}.wav`)
    if (await db.has(`shortholdtime-${message.author.id}`)) {
      message.channel.send('I finished recording because either I got disconnected, you left the voice chat or I forcibly stopped the recording. I attached the recording to this message. To play back your recording in a vc, use the command rplay. Your recording will be deleted in 30 minutes due to performance and privacy reasons (From my server, which means you won\'t be able to play the recording back but you will be able to listen to it via the attachment).')
      var attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(`./record-${message.author.id}.wav`)
      message.channel.send(attachment)
      setTimeout(() => {
        fs.unlinkSync(`./record-${message.author.id}.wav`)
      }, 30 * 1000 * 60)
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        fs.unlinkSync(`./record-${message.author.id}.wav`)
      }, 10 * 1000 * 60)
    }
  })
  client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async(oldState, newState) => {
    if (oldState.channelID === null) return;
    if ((client.users.cache.get(oldState.id)).bot) return;
    if (!newState.channelID === null) return;
    await db.set(`vcdatarecord-${message.author.id}`, oldState.channelID)
    writer.close()
  })
})
```

Comment: Have you tried other packages as well, like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wav) one?

Comment: Tried it, same problem occurs. The video is insanely long and is silent. If I play it through my bot using this: https://sourceb.in/CoGAKlcBVk then it's fine but I would like to be a playable file.